Analog to Feigenbaum constant for even and odd cycles
A picture is worth a thousand words, so starting off there's this peculiar aspect to the logistic map where it seems to have consistently-placed even and odd cycles after the onset of chaos:

Where notably it seems like all even and odd numbers are accounted for.
Based on these somewhat predictable cycles after the onset of chaos, I am wondering:

If the ratios of the e.g. (2k+1)-cycle to (2k + 3)-cycle converge
The value of the ratio if it converges (similar to the Feigenbaum constants).

